# Why hexadecimal color don't work with utf8 data URL’s for SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, utf-8

I'm wondering why i can't use **HEX colors** in style when i call an svg from **utf8 data url**.

When i call it with rgb color it work perfectly fine :

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><defs><style>.roundShape{fill:rgb(38, 167, 253);}</style></defs><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="roundShape" /></svg>'>
```

But, if i use HEX color, the svg does not display :

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><defs><style>.roundShape{fill:#26a7fd;}</style></defs><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="roundShape" /></svg>'>
```

Curiously, in base64 everything work's fine :

```
<img id='imgBase64'>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('imgBase64').src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><defs><style>.roundShape{fill:#26a7fd;}</style></defs><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="roundShape" /></svg>');
</script>
```

Is there a possibility to use HEX color with utf8 data url?

Comment: Why not just use the `<svg>` by itself.

Comment: Of course, i could. But this is just an exemple. I found this issue by creating a class to change color of a pre designed svg in a project where every object is build dynamically in JS. The structure of the app is not designed for calling svg by itself. I already have a solution by using base64 but i'm curious, i can't understand why the svg does not display in a very simple call like the code in the exemple.

Comment: Perhaps the '#' symbol should be escaped, because it's a fragment identifier?

Comment: I've had a similar issue with a SVG border-image to create [themebale circular dotted lines](https://codepen.io/scootman/pen/dyWZPKG) and as a workaround called transparentize in SCSS to force a RGBA encoding of the colors. There must be a better way

Comment: HEX colours are a bad way to describe colours. It worked on 199x where computer had just max 16 colours (256 the best one), so there were ample extra space. but since many years we have screens with 30 or more bits for colours, and we cannot represent it on web. We just need to get away of hex colours (CSS and SVG allows us to support more, and to make aware programmers that hex colour sucks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) so there is not a parse issue:

```js
document.getElementById('imgBase64').src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,'+encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><defs><style>.roundShape{fill:#26a7fd;}</style></defs><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="roundShape" /></svg>');
```

```html
<img id='imgBase64' />
```

Comment: ``encodeURI`` encodes every character not valid in a URI, in this SVG all that needs to be encoded is the **#** character, keeping all SVG readable in the Inspector (and no decoding required by the CPU)